# Custom Category Filter Dropdown Displaying Twice

Tags: php, wordpress, function, user-interface, wordpress-theming

I needed to build a dropdown category filter for my WordPress child theme. Here's what I have in my functions.php:

```
function blog_category_filter() {
        if
        ( $terms = get_terms
            ( array
                ('taxonomy' => 'category', // to make it simple I use default categories
                 'orderby' => 'name'
                ) 
            )
        ) : 
            // if categories exist, display the dropdown
            echo '<select name="category_filter"><option value="">Filter By Category</option>';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as an option value
                endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_category_filter' );
```

I call the function in my index.php like so:

```
<?php blog_category_filter() ?>
```

The dropdown is displaying twice, once at the very top of the page (where I do not want it to be) and again further down in the body (where I do want it to be).

When I look at the code in Dev Tools, I see the dropdown directly under the body tag, followed by stylesheets, WP scripts, the rest of the HTML, then my scripts. No idea why that is happening, but one catastrophe at a time, amirite?

Is this an enqueue issue? It's the only thing I can think of as I am totally lost on where to start.

Comment: You should remove `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blog_category_filter' );` from functions.php. enque_scripts should only be used when adding js or css files not for custom functions

Comment: `wp_enqueue_scripts` is called everytime site is loaded so you are calling twice once in functions.php and index.php.

Comment: It worked! I can't thank you enough, @Manjunath. I've been teaching myself WordPress and never learned enqueue should only be used when adding js or css files, not for custom functions.